# PuTTY/PSFTP & Pageant. Select particular key

Tags: putty

I have a windows box that we use for outgoing SFTP transfers. They're all scripted and I use PSFTP with PAGEANT to hold the private keys.

My problem is that over the last 12 months a new partner of this client has added a significant number of new connections each of which they insist upon having a new key pair for.

My problem is that now the connection that uses the last key in pageant gets 8 failed login attempts before finding the correct key on the ninth attempt. The admins at the other end of this have phoned us up and are asking what the problem is as their logs are flagging this as a failed hacking attempt every fifteen minutes, and they will automatically block the connection on the tenth failure.

I've read the [putty/pageant documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/puttydoc.txt) but can't see any way to force PSFTP to use only one key in pageant (a switch like -keyno x was what I was expecting to find)

I'm on the verge of re-creating the 'problem' connection and dropping its need for pageant entirely but that requires removing the passphrase from the keypair/including the pass phrase in the script. Whilst this is only sensitive rather than confidential data, we do make certain claims to our clients about security of connections and it includes language that suggests we follow best practice in these kinds of situations, so I'd like to not have to do that.

Answer (score 2):

According to some of the documentation found [here](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#6.1) you can instruct PSFTP to use a PuTTY saved session instead of a hostname. You can specify the key specifically in the saved session and then as long as it's loaded in pageant then it will work as you expect it to.

> Run PuTTY, and create a PuTTY saved session (see section 4.1.2) which
> specifies your private key file (see section 4.16.5). You will
> probably also want to specify a username to log in as (see section
> 4.12.2).
>
> In PSFTP, you can now use the name of the session instead of a hostname: type psftp sessionname, where sessionname is replaced by
> the name of your saved session.

EDIT:

Just read the link that you posted in your question and you're looking for section 6.3. That says that you can use an -i switch to specify a ppk file.

Comment: -i need you to enter the passphrase for the key each time it executes. With Pageant I only have to put them in after each reboot. The stored sessions might work.

Comment: Do you still have to enter the passphrase if the same key is loaded in pageant?

Comment: When you first load pageant it needs the passphrase for each key. From that point on no more passphrases are required. I have to manually launch Pageant after each reboot.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased my question wrong. If the key is already loaded in pageant and you reference the same key from PSFTP using -i do you still need to type in the password?